# Repairing link between shapefile and layer file?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, arcgis-10.2, layer-file

every time I open the same lyr file I have to do data/repair data source (link to the shp file).

I tried to save/export that shp file again, and create the new layer file as well, but every time the same thing happens. The Arc does not remember the link between these two.

Moreover, when I define the data source and the shp file appears in Arc, I have to define the symboloy from scratch (via properties/symbology/import dialogue)

Any ideas how to permanently define the link between the shp and layer file in ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop? (When drag lyr file to automatically link the shp file)

Comment: You can't fix it *without* creating a new layer (lyr) file, as for whatever reason those don't honor relative paths. However, if your shapefile isn't moving, and you repair the link and then create a new lyr file, it should be working. Is the shapefile in a remote location such as an external/usb/network drive?

Comment: What do you mean by "every time I open the same shp file I have to do data/repair data source"?  If it is using Add To Map, or drag and drop from the Catalog window to add the shapefile into your map then there should be no need to repair the data source because the aforementioned steps create the layer (and know its data source).  I think you must mean that you add ("open") an existing layer file.  An edit to your question would help clarify this.

Comment: In the properties of the layer (ArcCatalog) go to the *source* tab and hit the button *set data source* then find the shape file and hit OK, now the layer is pointing to real data. I forgot that layers can't have relative path names, it's MXDs' that can have relative paths.

Comment: @Michael Miles-Stimson. Yes, I don't want to have an .mxd file, just the shp and layer file, correctly and permanently linked.

Comment: @Chsri W: It is not working when I do so, and yes, the files are on my external HD. good point, and worth checking out, I will try to put it locally on my PC.

Comment: @PolyGeo: Yes, you are right, I will edit a question, the thing is happening when I add the layer file to the workspace (it is not linking the shape file correctly and it is not possible to fix the connection permanently). However, there is no way that shp file remembers the symbology (lyr file link)

Comment: It shouldn't matter where the shape file is. Arc may get stroppy if the path isn't in the folder connections. Does the path in the layer file (properties::source) actually point to the full path of the shape file?

Comment: @Michael: very interesting... when I fix the data source of the layer file in arc catalog an point  out to the relevant shp file, the interesting things happen :) when I drag and drop from catalogue to arc the layer file, the file opens but without symolobgy. When I go with 'Add data' in Arc the link is still broken :)

Comment: @Michael again :) when I do the same locally, the layer connection with the shape file is fixed. However, the added layer is not showing any symology, although I have defined the link between the lyr and shp file in the arc. Therefore, i need to go again in the Properties/Symbology/Import dialogue in arc... Any ideas how to fix that? And yes,all the paths are complete..

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson re "layers can't have relative path names, it's MXDs' that can have relative paths" I think that's actually incorrect. When you _create_ the layer you [specify](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000070000000) whether it's relative. There's no way to see or change this value but it's set internally - bad UX on Esri's part.

Comment: @StephenLead Thanks for pointing out the GP tool - I'm so used to doing it via right-click (which doesn't expose the option) I never thought to look for the GP. I always wondered where people were setting that. Supposedly with the right-click option it uses the setting for the current map document. However, per my first comment I have *never* had a lyr file honor relative paths, regardless of map doc settings. Maybe I've never used one created that way with the GP tool - worth some testing. And I agree - really wish Esri would make lyr files editable in some way be it plain text or a tool.

Comment: Mario - the one time I remember it loading data but not symbology was when the lyr file was created for a raster but being applied to vector data. Probably not the case here, but thought I'd mention it. As for external drives, I have had very unpredictable results when working from non-local drives. They tend to go to 'sleep' between accesses and wake-up delay causes Arc to have issues. @MichaelMiles-Stimson mentions folder connection paths, and that's another good idea to look at. Would you be able to post the lyr file and shapefile (or sample of it) we could test with?

Comment: Thank you @StephenLead, so I wasn't mistaken in my original comment, layers can be relative but *only* if you use the tool to export them. When you right click on a layer and *save as layer file* it doesn't give you a choice. I *knew* I had heard that layers could be relative before, just couldn't remember how. When you set the data source it doesn't check that the geometry is correct, you could be setting a polygon layer to a line shapefile. I suggest load the layer, fix the link and then use the tool to export the layer and delete the old one.

Comment: @StephenLead I think you should offer the Save To Layer File tool as an answer.  If it is not accepted then the question seems to have some contradictions so I think needs to be re-written with more attention to the differences between shapefiles, map layers and layer files.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Actually, lyr files can be relative regardless of whether you use the GP or right-click, depending on the map document properties - not only by using the tool - as my comment and Stephen's answer points out. I had utterly confused myself on exactly what relative path means/how it works. Mario: assuming your shapefile is in one location and does not move, if you save a lyr file anywhere (and do not move it), does adding that lyr file to a map not connect to the data? Or does the link only break when you move something (anything)?

Comment: Relative means *from where the link is*. If you have a layer file in the same folder as the shapefile then so long as you move both to the same folder it's ok. If the shapefile is in a subfolder (let's say .\data) then you would have to copy the layer and ensure the shapefile is in a subfolder called *data*. So you are saying the layer adopts the relative settings of the map document.. interesting. Not everything can be relative, even in a MXD, if the data is on another drive to the MXD/LYR then it's not relative. Hope that helps @ChrisW.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Actually that's not entirely true. Even if they're in the same folder, if you change the name of the folder (or move both to the same folder with a different name) the link breaks. At least according to my experience and testing last night. Other than that, yes, relative basically means the entire referenced tree can't change, but anything *above* that can (ie drive letters, other folders closer to root). And yes on the map doc settings - see [this help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000013000000).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the comment thread above, layer files and relative paths are a bit complicated.

The problem is that a layer file (*.lyr) can either hold absolute paths or relative paths, but there doesn't seem to be any (easy) way to ascertain which it uses, **after** the layer file has been created.

To create a layer file with relative paths, there are two options:

- in ArcMap, choose *> File > Map Document Properties > Store Relative Paths*, then right-click on the layer and *Save As Layer File*; or
- using the [Save To Layer File](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000070000000) geoprocessing tool, choose relative paths

(Obviously to choose absolute paths do the above with the other option chosen.)

So in your situation it sounds like you might need to recreate your layer file using either absolute paths or relative paths (depending on your workflow):

- add the broken layer file to ArcMap
- repair the source
- re-save a new *.lyr file using the appropriate path option
- delete the existing broken *.lyr file